# Emulator is in portrait but screen is in Landscape

Tags: android, android-emulator

Here Emulator is in portrait but screen is in Landscape how to fix this,i tried by deleting and re creating emulator with different sizes and different versions ,restarting eclipse , restarted my computer also.help me.
[image]

Comment: Don't know how it happened but you can use Ctrl+F12 to at least rotate the window to landscape. I just hope it wont rotate the emulator it self also.

Comment: What is the configuration of this emulator.

Comment: have you entered some programmatical rotation changes? i know that problem from camera-previews.

Answer (score 0):

Please try ctrl+F11

If it is in portrait mode goes to landscape.
Same key brings back to portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

will rotate the emulator to landscape mode